# xsl generate-id() function returns same id twice for different nodes

Tags: function, xslt-1.0

I have an input xml for a transformation like ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<AssetcustomerCollection xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/top/somens">
  <Assetcustomer xmlns="">
   ....
  </Assetcustomer>
  <Assetcustomer xmlns="">
    <accountklantid>000000123456789</accountklantid>
    <accountrowid>1-W8HQ1J</accountrowid>
    <adrestypeaccnt/>
    <adrestypecon/>
    <assetbankcode>1173</assetbankcode>
    <assetnumber>0000001234</assetnumber>
    <assetprodcode>1200</assetprodcode>
    <assetproduct>Overeenkomst Rekening-courant</assetproduct>
    <assetproductlocatie>00</assetproductlocatie>
    <assetstatus>Actief</assetstatus>
    <assetsubstatus>Lopende rekening</assetsubstatus>
    <assettypecode>0010</assettypecode>
    <contactklantid/>
    <contactrowid/>
    <primairaccount>Y</primairaccount>
    <primaircontact>N</primaircontact>
    <reltypeaccnt>Hoofdcontractant</reltypeaccnt>
    <reltypecon/>
    <rowidasset>1-X3XBMO</rowidasset>
    <rowidassetaccnt>1-X3XBMQ</rowidassetaccnt>
    <rowidassetcon/>
    <tnsidaccnt/>
    <tnsidcon/>
  </Assetcustomer>
  <Assetcustomer xmlns="">
   ....
  </Assetcustomer>
  <Assetcustomer xmlns="">
    <accountklantid/>
    <accountrowid/>
    <adrestypeaccnt/>
    <adrestypecon/>
    <assetbankcode>1173</assetbankcode>
    <assetnumber>0000004321</assetnumber>
    <assetprodcode>1201</assetprodcode>
    <assetproduct>WereldPas (Zakelijk)</assetproduct>
    <assetproductlocatie>00</assetproductlocatie>
    <assetstatus>Actief</assetstatus>
    <assetsubstatus>Lopende rekening</assetsubstatus>
    <assettypecode>0003</assettypecode>
    <contactklantid>000000987654321</contactklantid>
    <contactrowid>1-X17PLM</contactrowid>
    <primairaccount>N</primairaccount>
    <primaircontact>Y</primaircontact>
    <reltypeaccnt/>
    <reltypecon>Pasverantwoordelijke</reltypecon>
    <rowidasset>1-X3XBN0</rowidasset>
    <rowidassetaccnt/>
    <rowidassetcon>1-X3XBNE</rowidassetcon>
    <tnsidaccnt/>
    <tnsidcon/>
  </Assetcustomer>
  <Assetcustomer xmlns="">
   ....
  </Assetcustomer>
</AssetcustomerCollection>
```

When transforming this input xml i got an unexpected output (15 of the 16 input Assetcustomer nodes were transformed) I now have found the cause, but cannot explain why it occurs;

The following transformation returns the same id twice;

```
<xsl:element name="A">
  <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(key('AssetRowIDs',/ns0:AssetcustomerCollection/Assetcustomer[rowidasset = '1-X3XBMO']/*)[1])"/>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="B">
  <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(key('AssetRowIDs',/ns0:AssetcustomerCollection/Assetcustomer[rowidasset = '1-X3XBN0']/*)[1])"/>
</xsl:element>


<A>N10211</A>
<B>N10211</B>
```

While the generated id for any other node with a different rowidasset is different.

Any ideas before i start pulling my hair out ?

Peter

I do not know exactly why , but changing

```
<xsl:key name="AssetRowIDs" match="Assetcustomer" use="rowidasset"/>
```

into

```
<xsl:key name="AssetRowIDs" match="Assetcustomer" use="concat('-',rowidasset,'-')"/>
```

and

```
<xsl:for-each select="/ns0:AssetcustomerCollection/Assetcustomer[generate-id() = generate-id(key('AssetRowIDs',rowidasset)[1])]">
```

into

```
<xsl:for-each select="/ns0:AssetcustomerCollection/Assetcustomer[generate-id() = generate-id(key('AssetRowIDs',concat('-',rowidasset,'-'))[1])]">
```

Seems to generate a unique id for each node, still bugging me dat i do not understand the cause of it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the namespace? If the `ns0` prefix is bound to a wrong namespace URI, your query will in both cases yield an empty result set. Together with the same first argument for key, that, I imagine, will yield the same call to `key()` and thus the same ID.

Also I don't think the `key()` function does what you think it does: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_key.asp

In any case you can apply `generate-id()` directly on the node set for which you wish to calculate the ID.

Comment: Hi, i think i do understand generate-id() and key(). The xsl:key is defined before the template ( <xsl:key name="AssetRowIDs" match="Assetcustomer" use="rowidasset"/> ). In the original xsl i use the key the get a unique lists of assetrowids  ( <xsl:for-each select="/ns0:AssetcustomerCollection/Assetcustomer[generate-id() = generate-id(key('AssetRowIDs',rowidasset)[1])]">). I have done this more than once with expected results. Also in this transformation, except with 2 nodes in this input xml.